# error "a JNI error has occurred...check installation" followed by error "a Java Exception has occurred"

Tags: java

so I'm trying to make a hard drive manager thing, not really sure where I'm going with it yet but when I try to build this and run it on another computer it gives me 2 pop-ups

```
public static void main(String[]args){

    JFrame Smartdrives= new JFrame("Smart Drives");
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();

    panel.setBounds(10,100,200,500);
    panel.setBackground(Color.gray);

    File[] paths;
    paths = File.listRoots();
    DefaultListModel<String> drivelist = new DefaultListModel<>();
    JList<String> list = new JList<>(drivelist);

    for(File path:paths)
    {

        drivelist.addElement("drive: "+path);
        panel.add(list);
        list.setBounds(10,10, 75,75);
    }

    Smartdrives.add(panel);
    Smartdrives.setSize(1200,1000);
    Smartdrives.setResizable(false);
    Smartdrives.setLayout(null);
    panel.setLayout(null);
    Smartdrives.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

[i get greeted by this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZX1v.png)
[than this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6yM0.png)

the only thing has ive been able to find was someone saying "you cant use java package in the file name" im not doing that so I really have no clue how to fix

Comment: it works on the machine that I wrote it on, but when building artifacts and put it on my secondary computer to test it I get errors when I run the .jar

Comment: You should run with java (not with javaw that is probably bound to .jar files) and see if you get more info.

Comment: I would say this error does nt come from your code you posted. It seems an issue with a .dll (you are on Windows ?) that the other computer not has installed.